# Data exists but `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a `div` for each item in an array that is a property of `this.state`

However, I am getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on the line, `return outOfBudget.values.map((val, j)` 
Most of the posts on this subject have an issue because the data doesn't actually exist. I tried their solutions by wrapping the problematic line in an `if(outOfBudget)` statement, but the error persisted. I also log `outOfBudget` to console and see that it indeed exists.

Am I defining it incorrectly?

```
const BrokeBudget = ({outOfBudget}) => {

  return outOfBudget.values.map((val, j) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{val.name}</p>
        <p>{val.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

class Budget extends React.Component {
  state = {
      remainingBudget: 1600,
      data,
      pieChartData: [],
      outOfBudget: []
  };
  handleInputChange = event => {
    let { value, id, name } = event.target;
    value = parseInt(value, 10);


    const selectedQuestions = Object.assign(
      {},
      this.state.data.selectedQuestions
    );
    if (!selectedQuestions[name]) {
      selectedQuestions[name] = {};
    }
    selectedQuestions[name][id] = value;

    let newBudget = this.state.remainingBudget - value;
    if( newBudget >= 0){
      let pieSlice =
           {
             x: name,
             y: value
           };
           console.log(pieSlice);
           this.setState({
             data: {
               ...this.state.data,
               selectedQuestions
             },
             remainingBudget: newBudget,
             pieChartData: this.state.pieChartData.concat(pieSlice),
           });
    }
    else{

      let beyondBudget = {genre: name, amount: value}
      this.setState({
        data: {
          ...this.state.data,
          selectedQuestions
        },
        remainingBudget: newBudget,
        pieChartData: this.state.pieChartData,
        outOfBudget: {...this.state.outOfBudget, beyondBudget}
      });
    }


  };

  render() {
    const { data, remainingBudget, pieChartData, outOfBudget } = this.state;
    const questions = data.questions;
    return (
      <div>
        {questions.map((q, i) =>
            <UL key={i}>
              <li>
                <h4>{q.text}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Options
                  state={this.state}
                  q={q}
                  i={i}
                  handler={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </li>
            </UL>
          )}
        {Object.keys(data.selectedQuestions).length === 3 &&
          <div>
            <VictoryPie
              colorScale = "blue"
              data = {this.state.pieChartData}
              labels= {d => `${d.x}: ${d.y}%`}
              style={{ parent: { maxWidth: '50%' } }}
              />
              < BrokeBudget
                outOfBudget={outOfBudget}
              />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please ignore any strange cases (like `UL` I use Emotion for styling)

Comment: The error is saying that 'values' is undefined, not outOfBudget. You need to check that exists.

Comment: You're changing the state and setting `outOfBudget` to an object (`outOfBudget: {...this.state.outOfBudget, beyondBudget}`), you should be using `outOfBudget: [...this.state.outOfBudget, beyondBudget]` instead and get rid of `.values` in the `outOfBudget.values.map(...)` call

Comment: @Titus yup you're right!! I realized the object mistake after taking out values

Answer (score 0):

What is `.values` ?

Looks like you need `return outOfBudget.map((val, j) => {` without the `.values`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm assuming `outOfBudget` is an object. This you should be using the `values()` method instead of as a property. Also since you never use `j` consider using objects `values()`

Comment: `outOfBudget: []` is an array in `state`